# How to check download time and execution in Node js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, download, progress

I wanted to check how long did the downloading of each file and all file takes time if the download is slow or fast, How can we see and measure it on node js ? also would would be better it we can also consider memory. Thank you. By the way the final_list on the code below is an array of urls.

## my code on downloading files

```
var download = function (url, dest, callback) {

        request.get(url)
            .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) })
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest))
            .on('close', callback);

    };

    final_list.forEach(function (str) {
        var filename = str.split('/').pop();

        console.log('Downloading ' + filename);

        download(str, filename, function () { console.log('Finished Downloading' + "" + filename) });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Ways to measure time:

1. Use [`process.hrtime.bigint()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_bigint) (high-resolution).
2. Use [`console.time` with `console.timeEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/timeEnd).

#### Measure memory

Use [`process.memoryUsage()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage).

Here is your code updated with all the above methods.

```js
final_list.forEach(function (str) {
    var filename = str.split('/').pop();

    console.log('Downloading ' + filename);
    // console.time(filename);
    var start = process.hrtime.bigint();

    download(str, filename, function () {
        console.log('Finished Downloading' + "" + filename)
        // console.timeEnd(filename);
        var end = process.hrtime.bigint();
        var took = Number(end - start) / 1000000;
        console.log(`${filename}: ${took}ms`);
        console.log('Total used memory:', process.memoryUsage().heapUsed);
    });
});
```

Comment: process.memoryUsage().heapUsed , how do we know if it is in KB , MB or GB ?

Comment: It's measured in bytes. See the docs: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage.
I would also suggest you to read https://www.dynatrace.com/news/blog/understanding-garbage-collection-and-hunting-memory-leaks-in-node-js/ for a deeper understanding of the "V8’s Memory Scheme"

Comment: Let's continue on chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199401/room-for-avraham-and-mr-rajiv-kumar